# Draw a line using OpenGL|ES in Android NDK using C++

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

I want to draw a line in my Android NDK app using OpenGL|ES.

I am using the following code to draw the line on the screen.

```
GLfloat line[] = { 
                     0,0,0,
                     100,100,0
                  };

GLfloat colors[] = {
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
                    };
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, line);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
glFlush();
```

The above code will paint a Line on the Screen, but the issue I am facing is that if I change the coordinates in the array `line` e.g.

```
GLfloat line[] = {
                      0,0,0,
                      5,5,0
                 };
```

then also same line will be drawn on the screen i.e. there will be no change in the length of the line. Output attched:
[image]

what is the reason for this abnormal behavior ?

Comment: It is not the same line, you just don't see the remaining part of it when you change x and y to 5. Try values lower than 1 and see if it changes anything. Values with a different slope should also help.

Comment: ok. I also want to know that do coordinates `0,0,0` represents the center of the screen in case of opengl|es.

Comment: Depends on your viewport and camera settings. But the default viewport coordinates streches from -1 to 1, top right being (1,1) and bottom left being (-1, -1). So yes, in default condition (0,0) is the center of the screen. Note that the screen width and height is different though the coordinates are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying matrices the default OpenGL coordinates are normalized (mapped 0-1). (0,0) is the center of the screen, (1,0) is the center right side, (0, -1) is the bottom of the screen, etc.

In your example (5,5) and (100,100) are in exactly the same direction relative to the center and offscreen so that is why you see the same line in both.